# Echo will not display any value retrieved from json_decode()

Tags: php, json, echo

I have an extremely simple JSON object that looks like the following:

```
var data =
{
    "id" : 1
}
```

I then decode this in PHP:

```
$decoded_data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));  //this works
$id = intval($decoded_data->id); //in my debugger this is equal to 1 as expected
```

I then proceed to pass the $id variable into a function that queries the database and returns a set of 'Sub Activities'

```
$sub_activities = alp_get_all_sub_activities($id);  //this function works as expected and returns the correct result set
```

Now that I have the Sub Activities for the designated $id, I attempt to access them using a loop:

```
foreach ($sub_activities as $activity) {
    echo __("<td><a id='" . $activity->id . "' href='' title='Activity'><div style=' border: 3px solid purple; width: 200px; height: 200px; overflow: scroll;'>" . $activity->name . "<br />" . $activity->id . "<br />" . $activity->description) . "</div></a></td>";
}
```

My problem is: echo displays nothing when $id is set to intval($decoded_data->id), but when I hardcode $id = 1 then everything works as expected and shows in my browser.  I'm not quite sure how to approach this problem, because my debugger is telling me that when I set $id = intval($decoded_data->id); that $id is equal to 1.  I can do arithmetic with this number and it seems like it behaves as any integer would, but for some reason echo and print() will not display anything.

If anyone has any insight I'd really appreciate your input.

Comment: How do your fetch an array from the db - assoc, num or both? Did you try printing the sub_activities as an array (using print_r)?

Comment: I donno, there is no way to know, because we have no idea what the `__()` function does.  Have you tried using `true` as the second parameter of json_decode ?

Comment: AR - I'm using wordpress's db function get_results() to retrieve the entire contents of the table - and it appears to return as two dimensional associative array:

Comment: like this:  [0] field 1 => value, field 2 => value  [1] field 1 => value, field 2 => value ...etc

Comment: Good suggestion with print_r - I tried this and it prints only 'Array()' - but when I pass in a hardcoded value print_r displays the entire contents of the array

Comment: Jeremy - the __() function is just a translation function for wordpress and I get the same result when I remove __() from echo

Comment: Yes, I have tried putting 'true' as the second argument - which returns an array - and when I attempt to access the value it gives me the same result!  Ahh -- thanks for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with ajax in Wordpress with Buddypress installed.  Buddypress was sending the request elsewhere for its own purposes.  I just created my own javascript namespace object and rerouted the data.  Here are tutorials that helped me figure this out:

http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

http://www.garyc40.com/2010/03/5-tips-for-using-ajax-in-wordpress/

JSON now works perfectly.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

try accessing the value like this:

```
$id = $decoded_data->{'id'};
$id = (int)$decoded_data->{'id'};
$id = intval($decoded_data->{'id'});
$id = (int)$decoded_data->id;
```

Instead of this:

```
$id = intval($decoded_data->id);
```

Thinking about this a little more is JSON treating the integer as a boolean? Could you try

```
var data =
{
    "id" : "1"
}
```

Comment: Phill Thanks for the suggestions!  I've tried all of the above with the same result.  I also tried passing in different numbers to id and still no change.